# Importing Digital Juice Sound FX IV metadata to Audiofinder

Tags: sfx, library-sound-effects, sound-library

does anyone know if there is a text file for DJ's SFX IV? I want to be able to search the SFX in Audiofinder instead of the crappy Juicer 3 app. It's painful to keep having to run 2 search engines at the same time so if anyone knows of any solution do let me know.

FYI, DJ shut down their forum, and their support doesn't seem to be the most responsive. They've also taken out the old libraries and replaced it with a single new one. I think its a useful little library and find it a shame that I haven't been able to utilise it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem a few years ago, so I made Excel table for it manually from Juicer searcher, you can download it here - hope it'll help:

http://liquidblasted.net/other/juicy_sound_tracklist_4.zip

UPD: Here is a link to all tracklists for Digital Juice I, II, III and IV volumes:

http://liquidblasted.net/other/digital_juice_tracklists.zip

Comment: Thanks mate! Not exactly what I was hoping for but this certainly gives me more options!

Comment: That is great work.
Did you type manually or you got it in anyway from the Juicer software?
I am trying to do the same with the VOL II and III Thanks

Comment: That was long time ago but as I remember I opened playlists via Juicer's searcher, made printscreens and recognized it into text with FineReader - that was the most "fastest" & possible way to export file's descriptions from their searcher into text format. Costs me about 1 day yeah... 

But after that it was possible to reorganize those text data with the help of Excel table into filenames like "SFXNUMBER_DESCRIPTION.WAV" and rename all wavs via Total Commander (Total Commander has possibility to rename a list of files according to given textfile with your own list in it, just in one click).

Comment: Wait 1 week you you had a time Benfor - I'll get in touch with my work PC next Monday to see, if I have the same tables for I...III volumes also

Comment: So the next monday is here and I found all tracklists - see update in my answer

Comment: I know this is more than a year later but I just happened upon your xls files for the Digital Juice library and was wondering... it seems as though they don't cover all the files. For instance, the spreadsheet for library III has headers that say "III disk 09" and it looks as though indeed it only has the track list for disk 09 of that set. Sadly Digital Juice has gone to a different system so the original Juicer application no longer exists, and I'm not sure how I would recreate these files. So - I was hoping perhaps you had the whole set. Any chance? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Just look at the sheets - every CD is on it's separate sheet inside the xls